# Property 'selectionStart' does not exist on type 'ReactInstance'. Property 'selectionStart' does not exist on type 'Component<any, {}, any>'.ts￼

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting typescript error. here I am sharing my code with error which I am getting

**code: 1 DateField.tsx**

```
handleDate(value: string){ 
    const inputField  = this.refs.input;
    const caretStart = inputField.selectionStart ;
    const caretEnd = inputField.selectionEnd;
```

**Error: 1**

any
Property 'selectionStart' does not exist on type 'ReactInstance'.
Property 'selectionStart' does not exist on type 'Component<any, {}, any>'.ts(2339)

**code: 2 DateField.tsx**

```
completeField(value:any, fieldIndex:any) {
    return _.padStart(
      value,
      FIELDS[fieldIndex].label.length,
      FIELDS[fieldIndex].pad
    );
  }
```

**error: 2**
(property) pad: number
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | undefined'.ts(2345)

**code:3 DropDown.tsx**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.refs.list) {
      const option = this.refs["option-" + this.props.value];
      this.refs.list._scrollTop =
        option.offsetTop - (this.props.height - option.offsetHeight) / 2;
    }
  }
```

**error:3** 
any
Property '_scrollTop' does not exist on type 'ReactInstance'.
Property '_scrollTop' does not exist on type 'Component<any, {}, any>'.ts(

**Code:4 DropDown.tsx**

```
render() {
    const { value, isOpen } = this.state;
    const current = _.find(this.props.options, (option) => {
      // HACK because select returns string
      return (
        option.value === value || option.value.toString() === value.toString()
      );
    });
```

**error:4**
const value: string
This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)

**DateField.tsx**

```
import _ from "lodash";
import moment from "moment";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./DateField.scss";

const SEPARATOR = "-";
const POSSIBLE_SEPARATORS = ["-", "/", " ", String.fromCharCode(13)];
const FIELDS = [
  {
    label: "DD",
    pad: 0
  },
  {
    label: "MM",
    pad: 0
  },
  {
    label: "YYYY",
    pad: moment().year()
  }
];

const HINT = FIELDS.map((field) => field.label).join(SEPARATOR);
const MAX_LENGTH = HINT.length;

type OnChangePropType = {
  day: number;
  month: number;
  year: number;
  value: any;
  resolvedDate: any;
};


interface IProps {
  value: any;
  onChange: (param: OnChangePropType) => void;
}

interface IState {
  value: any;
  errors: Array<Object>;
  hint: string;
}

export class DateField extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  static defaultProps = {
    onChange: () => {}
  };

  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: props.value || "",
      hint: HINT,
      errors: []
    };
  }

  /**
   * Find difference between words (i.e. insertion or edit point)
   * @param {*} value
   * @param {*} lastValue
   */
  findDifference(value:any, lastValue:any) {
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length && i < lastValue.length; i++) {
      if (value[i] !== lastValue[i]) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return value.length - 1;
  }

  findClosestSeparatorFieldIndex({ value, editIndex }:{ value:any, editIndex:any }) {
    const partialValue = value.substr(0, editIndex + 1);
    let numSeparators = partialValue.match(new RegExp(SEPARATOR, "g"));

    if (numSeparators) {
      // FIELD index from zero (['DD', 'MM', 'YYYY'])
      return numSeparators.length - 1;
    }
    return null;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProp:IProps) {
    const { value } = this.props;
    if(prevProp.value !==  value && value) {
      this.handleDate(value);
    }
  }

  handleDate(value: string){ 
    const inputField  = this.refs.input;
    const caretStart = inputField.selectionStart ;
    const caretEnd = inputField.selectionEnd;

    // e.preventDefault();
    let { hint } = this.state;
    // let value = val;
    console.log("value", value);
    const errors = [];

    // swap all possible separators for correct one
    value = value.replace(
      new RegExp(`[${POSSIBLE_SEPARATORS.join("")}]`, "g"),
      SEPARATOR
    );

    // remove non-valid chars (not sep or digit)
    value = value.replace(new RegExp(`[^${SEPARATOR}0-9]`, ""), "");

    let editIndex = this.findDifference(value, this.state.value);
    let fieldToCompleteIndex = null;

    // find attempts at splitting
    if (value.charAt(editIndex) === SEPARATOR) {
      // const allSeparators = new RegExp(SEPARATOR, 'g').exec(value);
      // console.log('all', allSeparators);
      // const closestSeparator = _.find(allSeparators, (match, i) => {
      //   return editIndex < match.index ? i : false;
      // });

      fieldToCompleteIndex = this.findClosestSeparatorFieldIndex({
        value,
        editIndex
      });
      // console.log(fieldToCompleteIndex);
      // if (editIndex >
      // if (editIndex < 2) {
      //   completeComponent = 'day';
      // }
      // console.log(editIndex, 'YES');
    }

    // fix value by removing non-digits
    value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    const maxLength = HINT.replace(SEPARATOR, "").length;

    // size limit
    if (value.length > maxLength) {
      value = value.substr(0, maxLength);
    }

    // split into fields
    let day = value.substr(0, 2);
    let month = value.substr(2, 2);
    let year = value.substr(4, 4);

    // const resolvedDate = this.resolveDate({ day, month, year })
    // console.log(resolvedDate);

    if (fieldToCompleteIndex === 0) {
      day = this.completeField(day, fieldToCompleteIndex);
    }
    if (fieldToCompleteIndex === 1) {
      month = this.completeField(month, fieldToCompleteIndex);
    }
    if (fieldToCompleteIndex === 2) {
      year = this.completeField(year, fieldToCompleteIndex);
    }
    // editIndex++;

    let resolvedDate = null;
    if (day && month && year) {
      resolvedDate = moment([year, +month -1  , day]);
      if (!resolvedDate.isValid()) {
        errors.push("Invalid");
        // console.log(resolvedDate);
      }
    }

    value =
      day +
      (month || fieldToCompleteIndex === 0 ? SEPARATOR + month : "") +
      (year || fieldToCompleteIndex === 1 ? SEPARATOR + year : "");

    // edit hint to remove replaced chars
    hint = HINT.substr(value.length);

    this.setState({ value, hint, errors });
    this.props.onChange({
      day: parseInt(day, 10),
      month: parseInt(month, 10) - 1,
      year: parseInt(year, 10),
      value,
      resolvedDate
    });
    // console.log(
    //   "caretStart",
    //   caretStart,
    //   "caretEnd",
    //   caretEnd,
    //   "editIndex",
    //   editIndex
    // );
  }

  change(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
   this.handleDate(e.target.value.toString());
    // requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    //   inputField.selectionStart = editIndex;
    //   inputField.selectionEnd = editIndex;
    // });
  }

  // resolveDate({ day, month, year }) {
  //   const today = moment();
  //   day  = parseInt(day) || 1;
  //   month = parseInt(month) || 0;
  //   year = parseInt(year) || today.year();

  //   let resolvedDate = moment([year, month, day]);
  //   console.log(resolvedDate);
  //   // if (parseInt(day) > ) {
  //   //   day = 1;
  //   // }
  //   if (!month || parseInt(month) === 0) {
  //     month = today.month();
  //   }

  //   return {
  //     day,
  //     month,
  //     year,
  //   };
  // }
  
/**
   * Find difference between words (i.e. insertion or edit point)
   * @param {*} length
   * @param {*} lastValue
   */
  completeField(value:any, fieldIndex:any) {
    return _.padStart(
      value,
      FIELDS[fieldIndex].label.length,
      FIELDS[fieldIndex].pad
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { value, hint, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="field">
          <div className="field-hint">
            <span className="hint-filled">{value}</span>
            {hint}
          </div>
          <input
            className="field-input"
            onChange={(e) => this.change(e)}
            value={value}
            ref="input"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="field-errors">
          {errors.map((error: React.ReactNode, i: number) => (
            <div className="field-errors-item" key={i}>
              {error}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**DropDOwn.tsx**

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DropdownArrow from "../../assets/dropdown-arrow.svg";
import "./Dropdown.scss";

type OptionsPropType = {
  value: number;
  label: string;
};

interface IProps {
  value: string;
  height: number;
  options: Array<OptionsPropType>;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

interface IState {
  isOpen: boolean;
  value: string;
}

export class Dropdown extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  listRef = null;

  constructor(props:IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      value: props.value
    };
  }

  change(value:string) {
    this.setState({ value });
    this.props.onChange(value);
    this.close();
  }

  onOutsideClicked = (e:any) => {
    // only outside clicks allowed
    // if (this.refs.container && this.refs.container.contains(e.target)) {
    //   return;
    // }
    // document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.onOutsideClicked);
    this.close();
  };

  toggle() {
    const isOpen = !this.state.isOpen;
    this.setState({ isOpen });
    if (isOpen) {
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onOutsideClicked);
    }
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    if (props.value !== this.state.value) {
      this.setState({ value: props.value });
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.refs.list) {
      const option = this.refs["option-" + this.props.value];
      this.refs.list._scrollTop =
        option.offsetTop - (this.props.height - option.offsetHeight) / 2;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { value, isOpen } = this.state;
    const current = _.find(this.props.options, (option) => {
      // HACK because select returns string
      return (
        option.value === value || option.value.toString() === value.toString()
      );
    });

    const list = _.map(this.props.options, (option) => (
      <div
        ref={`option-${option.value}`}
        className={`dropdown-option ${
          value === option.value ? "dropdown-option--selected" : ""
        }`}
        onClick={() => this.change(option.value)}
        key={option.value}
      >
        {option.label}
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div
        className={`dropdown ${isOpen ? "dropdown--open" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => this.toggle()}
        ref="container"
      >
        <div className="dropdown-label">{current.label}</div>
        <div className="dropdown-arrow">
          <img src={DropdownArrow} />
        </div>
        {/* <select onChange={(e) => this.change(e.target.value)} defaultValue={value}>{list}</select> */}
        {isOpen ? (
          <div
            className="dropdown-list"
            style={{ maxHeight: this.props.height + "px" }}
            ref="list"
          >
            {list}
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Widget.tsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import moment from "moment";
import { find as _find } from "lodash";
import { Dropdown } from "./dropdown/Dropdown";
import { DateField } from "./date-field/DateField";
import { MonthNavigator } from "./month-navigator/MonthNavigator";
import "./Widget.scss";

const MIN_YEAR = 1900;
const MAX_YEAR = moment().year() + 5;

type DatePropType = {
  day: number;
  month: number;
  year: number;
};

type FromPropType = {
  day: number;
  month: number;
  year: number;
};

type UntilPropType = {
  day: number;
  month: number;
  year: number;
};

type FromToUntilPropType = {
  from: FromPropType;
  until: UntilPropType;
};

interface IProps {
  disabledRanges: Array<FromToUntilPropType>;
  date:Date
}

interface IState {
  date: Date;
  day: number;
  month: number;
  year: number;
  selectedDay: number;

  selectedMonth: number;
  selectedYear: number;
  dropdownHeight: number;
  selectedDate: string;
}

export class Widget extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    const date = props.date || moment();
    this.state = {
      date,
      day: date.date(),
      month: date.month(),
      year: date.year(),
      selectedDay: 10,
      selectedMonth: 2,
      selectedYear: 2019,
      dropdownHeight: 200,
      selectedDate: '',
    };
  }

  // createDay({ dayNumber, startDay }) {
  //   const { day, month, year, date, selectedDay } = this.state;

  //   let state = '';
  //   if (month === date.month() && year === date.year()) {
  //     state = dayNumber === selectedDay
  //       ? 'Widget-day--selected'
  //       : (dayNumber === day
  //         ? 'Widget-day--current'
  //         : ''
  //       );
  //   }
  //   const style = {};
  //   if (startDay) {
  //     style = { ...style, gridColumnStart: startDay};
  //     startDay = 0;
  //   }
  //   return (
  //     <div className={`Widget-day ${state}`} onClick={() => this.changeDay({ day: dayNumber)}
  //       style={style}
  //       key={dayNumber}>
  //       {dayNumber}
  //     </div>
  //   );
  // }

  /**
   *
   * @param {object} param
   * @param {string} param.type   Can be: 'previous' | 'next' | `null` where `null` is current
   */
  createDays() {
    const daysInWeek = 7;
    const {
      day,
      month,
      year,
      date,
      selectedDay,
      selectedMonth,
      selectedYear
    } = this.state;
    const list = [];
    const daysInCurrentMonth = moment([year, month, day]).daysInMonth();
    const daysInPreviousMonth = moment([year, month, day])
      .subtract(1, "month")
      .daysInMonth();
    let startDay = moment([year, month, 1]).day();

    const numPreviousDaysShown = Math.max(startDay - 1, 0);
    let numNextDaysShown =
      daysInWeek - ((daysInCurrentMonth + numPreviousDaysShown) % daysInWeek);
    if (numNextDaysShown === daysInWeek) {
      numNextDaysShown = 0;
    }

    let from = 0 - numPreviousDaysShown;
    let until = daysInCurrentMonth + numNextDaysShown;

    const classNamePrefix = "widget-day--";

    for (let i = from; i < until; i++) {
      let dayNumber = i + 1;
      const classNames = [];
      const style = {};
      let isDisabled = false;
      let type = "";
      let referenceDate = moment([year, month, 1]);

      if (dayNumber <= 0) {
        dayNumber = daysInPreviousMonth + i + 1;
        type = "previous";
        referenceDate.subtract(1, "month");
      } else if (dayNumber > daysInCurrentMonth) {
        dayNumber = i - daysInCurrentMonth + 1;
        type = "next";
        referenceDate.add(1, "month");
      } else {
        referenceDate.date(dayNumber);
      }

      // if (startDay) {
      //   style = { ...style, gridColumnStart: startDay};
      //   startDay = 0;
      // }

      if (type) {
        classNames.push(`${classNamePrefix}${type}`);
      }

      if (
        referenceDate.year() === selectedYear &&
        referenceDate.month() === selectedMonth &&
        dayNumber === selectedDay
      ) {
        classNames.push(`${classNamePrefix}selected`);
      } else if (
        dayNumber === day &&
        month === date.month() &&
        year === date.year()
      ) {
        classNames.push(`${classNamePrefix}current`);
      }

      if (
        this.checkIsInDisabledRange({
          day: dayNumber,
          month: referenceDate.month(),
          year: referenceDate.year()
        })
      ) {
        isDisabled = true;
        classNames.push(`${classNamePrefix}disabled`);
      }

      const clickAction = !isDisabled
        ? () =>
            this.changeDay({
              day: dayNumber,
              month: referenceDate.month(),
              year: referenceDate.year()
            })
        : () => {};

      list.push(
        <div
          className={`widget-day ${classNames.join(" ")}`}
          onClick={clickAction}
          style={style}
          key={i}
        >
          {dayNumber}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return list;
  }

  /**
   *  Disabled ranges = array of from, until
   *
   * @param {number} day
   * @param {number} month
   * @param {number} year
   */
  checkIsInDisabledRange({ day, month, year }: DatePropType) {
    const current = moment([year, month, day]);
    return (
      _find(this.props.disabledRanges, (range) => {
        const from = moment([
          range.from.year,
          range.from.month,
          range.from.day
        ]);
        const until = moment([
          range.until.year,
          range.until.month,
          range.until.day
        ]);
        return current.isSameOrAfter(from) && current.isSameOrBefore(until);
      }) != null
    );
  }

  createDayLabels() {
    const list = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      const label = moment().day(i).format("ddd");
      list.push(
        <div className="widget-label" key={i}>
          {label}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return list;
  }

  createMonthSelector(current:any) {
    const list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      list.push({ value: i, label: moment().month(i).format("MMMM") });
    }
    return (
      <Dropdown
        onChange={(value) => this.changeMonth(value)}
        value={current}
        options={list}
        height={this.state.dropdownHeight}
      />
    );
  }

  createYearSelector(current:any) {
    const list = [];
    for (let i = MIN_YEAR; i < MAX_YEAR; i++) {
      list.push({ value: i, label: moment().year(i).format("YYYY") });
    }
    return (
      <Dropdown
        onChange={(value) => this.changeYear(value)}
        value={current}
        options={list}
        height={this.state.dropdownHeight}
      />
    );
  }

  changeDay({ day, month, year }:{ day:any, month:any, year:any }) {
    console.log(
      day,
      month,
      year,
      moment([year, month, day]).format("DD MM YYYY")
    );
      this.setState({selectedDate: moment([year, month, day]).format("DDMMYYYY")});
    // let { month, year } = this.state;
    // let reference = moment([year, month, 1]);
    // const day = value + 1;
    // if (value < 0) {
    //   reference.subtract(1, 'month');
    //   reference.date(reference.daysInMonth() + day);
    // }
    // else {
    //   reference.date(day);
    // }
    // console.log(reference.date(), month, year);

    // moving to previous or next
    this.setState({
      selectedDay: day,
      selectedMonth: month,
      selectedYear: year,
      month,
      year
    });
  }

  changeMonth(value:any ) {
    this.setState({ month: value });
  }

  changeYear(value:any) {
    this.setState({ year: value });
  }

  previousMonth() {
    let { day, month, year } = this.state;
    const previousMonth = moment([year, month, day]).add(-1, "month");
    this.setState({
      day: previousMonth.date(),
      month: previousMonth.month(),
      year: previousMonth.year()
    });
  }

  nextMonth() {
    let { day, month, year } = this.state;
    const nextMonth = moment([year, month, day]).add(1, "month");
    this.setState({
      day: nextMonth.date(),
      month: nextMonth.month(),
      year: nextMonth.year()
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.dropdownHeight !== this.refs.body.clientHeight) {
      this.setState({ dropdownHeight: this.refs.body.clientHeight });
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ dropdownHeight: this.refs.body.clientHeight });
  }

  // onChangeField({ value, day, month, year }) {
  //   console.log('change', value, day, month, year);
  //   if (day && month && year) {
  //     this.setState({ selectedDay: day, selectedMonth: month, selectedYear: year });
  //   }
  // }

  onChangeField({ day, month, year, resolvedDate }) {
    if (
      resolvedDate &&
      resolvedDate.isValid() &&
      resolvedDate.year() >= MIN_YEAR &&
      resolvedDate.year() <= MAX_YEAR
    ) {
      this.changeDay({ day, month, year });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { month, year, selectedDate } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="date-picker">
        <DateField onChange={(value) => this.onChangeField(value)} value={selectedDate} />
        <div className="widget">
          <div className="header">
            <MonthNavigator
              onClick={() => this.previousMonth()}
              direction="left"
            />
            <div className="header-month">
              {this.createMonthSelector(month)}
            </div>
            <div className="header-year">{this.createYearSelector(year)}</div>
            <MonthNavigator
              onClick={() => this.nextMonth()}
              direction="right"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="widget-body" ref="body">
            {this.createDayLabels()}
            {this.createDays()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Full repo
https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-night-nqvyy

Comment: Most of your errors are due to refs not working properly.  You are using [legacy string refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) so you should really rewrite this to one of the newer syntaxes.

Comment: please help me i cant figure out the bug new in typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the [legacy string refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs).  You should update to one of the newer ref syntaxes, [explained here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

In `DateField` you have a ref to an input element.

Inside the constructor, call `createRef` to create an empty ref, and use the generic to tell it what DOM element we will point our ref to.

```
this.inputRef = createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
```

Typescript will give you an error "Property 'inputRef' does not exist on type 'DateField'".  So you need to declare that the property exists.  Add this to the top of your class.  Actually if we have the generic here then we don't really need to say it again in `createRef`.

```
private readonly inputRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
```

To use the ref, you access the `.current` property.  We use the `?.` operator because current property might not exist if the ref hasn't been set yet.

```
handleDate(value: string) {
    const caretStart = this.inputRef.current?.selectionStart;
    const caretEnd = this.inputRef.current?.selectionEnd;
...
```

To attach the ref to the `input` element, in the `render()` function, do this

```
<input
    ....
    ref={this.inputRef}
/>
```

There's a lot of other issues.  I fixed some but not all [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-morning-tu2nw).

Comment: Thanks LInda :)  now I can handle god bless you :))